# Comparing ID from Search and an entry in Database (PHP MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I've got this.

```
<form id="" class="searchbar" action="searchAppt.php" method="get">
       <input id="" size="5" type="number" name="terms" min="0"  class = "sbar" placeholder="Enter appointment ID " oninput="validity.valid||(value='');"
                   onblur="if (this.value == '') {
                                this.value = 'Enter ID #';
                            }"
                   onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter ID #') {
         this.value = '';
     }"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <button type="submit" class = "btn">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search 
            </button>
        </form>
```

Which passes to this. Right now it's getting all the ID's the "LIKE" but I'm basically wanting to see if the number they searched matches an ID from the appointments table. (appointment ID) the appointment ID is simply "id"

```
if (filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, "terms")) {
    $terms_str = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'terms', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
} else {
    echo "There were no appointments found.";
    include ('includes/footer.php');
    exit;
}
            //explode the search terms into an array
         //   $terms = explode(" ", $terms_str);


  $sql = "SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE 1";
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $sql .= " AND id LIKE '%$term%' AND email = '". $_SESSION['email'] ."' 
                ";
            }

            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                echo "<br /> <br /> <center><h1> Your Tickets </h1></center><br /> <hr><br /> <table border = 1><tr><th>Ticket #</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Phone #</th><th>Building</th><th>Room #</th><th>Issue</th><th>Appt. Start Time</th><th>Appt. End Time</th></tr>";
                // output data of each row
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["fname"]."</td><td>".$row["lname"]."</td><td>".$row["phonenum"]."</td><td>".$row["building"]."</td><td>".$row["room"]."</td><td>".$row["issue"]."</td><td>".$row["start_time"]."</td><td>".$row["end_time"]."</td></tr>";
                }
                echo "</table>";
            } else {
                echo "<br /> <br />Your search <i>'$terms_str'</i> did not match any appointments";
                include ('includes/footer.php');
                exit;
            }

        ?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `WHERE id = '%$term%'`? Not sure what the `WHERE 1` is doing...

Comment: @ObsidianAge `WHERE 1` probably should be `LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0`... but the surrounding text uses the plural form, so this appears unlikely; nevertheless `ID` sounds alike a single record. it's confusing.

Comment: @ObsidianAge @Martin Zeitler I don't think I need the for each loop, I took it from a previous project and was just trying to make it work. When I try just `WHERE id = '%term%'`, it is still not pulling that specific row I want rather just saying it doesn't not match my search.

Comment: where are you are taking value of `$term` ? you have commentted out that part.